# I'm making a shutdown timer in batch and got a error while making it user friendly

Tags: batch-file

When I entered nothing for the first option, as a user may do accidentally, the program crashed with a error message:

> goto was unexpected at this time.

```
@echo off
title Shutdown Timer
color 7c
echo.
echo SHUTDOWN TIMER 1.0
echo.
:start
echo Shutdown in?           
echo 1h, 2h, 3h, 4h, 5h, 6h, 7h, 8h, 9h, 10h,
set /p hour=
if %hour% == 1h goto onehour
if %hour% == 2h goto twohour
if %hour% == 3h goto threehour
if %hour% == 4h goto fourhour
if %hour% == 5h goto fivehour
if %hour% == 6h goto sixhour
if %hour% == 7h goto sevenhour
if %hour% == 8h goto eighthour
if %hour% == 9h goto ninehour
if %hour% == 10h goto tenhour
cls
echo.
echo SHUTDOWN TIMER 1.0
echo.
echo.
echo Please enter a valid option.
echo.
goto start
:onehour
```

Is there a way that will put the user to the start when nothing is entered, or another fix for this issue? For example, `if %hour% == "nothing" goto start`.

In this image you can see the error with echo on. Can someone please help me with this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh man, you are *so close*!

To prevent an error when the user enters no input, simply put quotation marks around **both** things you're comparing.

```
if "%hour%" == "1h" goto onehour
if "%hour%" == "2h" goto twohour
if "%hour%" == "3h" goto threehour
if "%hour%" == "4h" goto fourhour
if "%hour%" == "5h" goto fivehour
if "%hour%" == "6h" goto sixhour
if "%hour%" == "7h" goto sevenhour
if "%hour%" == "8h" goto eighthour
if "%hour%" == "9h" goto ninehour
if "%hour%" == "10h" goto tenhour
```

This way, when the user enters nothing, the `if` statement will still have something on both sides to keep it from having a syntax error.

```
if "" == "1h" goto onehour
```